# Magnolia Activation Module (version 5.1.0) Ensures that the key property 'magnolia.author.key.location' is present in the Magnolia properties file

Tags: magnolia

I have checked out the following example project ant tried to get it started with magnolia 5 
http://svn.magnolia-cms.com/svn/community/magnolia/tags/magnolia-4.3.1/magnolia-empty-webapp

I have updated maven dependencies, fixed a ton of exeptions and errors and my magnolia-empty-webapp pom.xml looks now like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <parent>
    <artifactId>magnolia-project</artifactId>
    <groupId>info.magnolia</groupId>
    <version>5.2.4</version>
    <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
  </parent>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <artifactId>magnolia-empty-webapp</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <name>magnolia-empty-webapp</name>
  <description>The basic Magnolia webapp on which projects can depend.</description>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>with-optional-modules</id>
      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>info.magnolia</groupId>
          <artifactId>magnolia-module-workflow</artifactId>
          <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>info.magnolia</groupId>
          <artifactId>magnolia-module-dms</artifactId>
          <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>info.magnolia</groupId>
          <artifactId>magnolia-module-samples</artifactId>
          <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.magnolia</groupId>
        <artifactId>magnolia-templating</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.magnolia</groupId>
        <artifactId>magnolia-core</artifactId>
        <!-- <version>5.2.4</version> -->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.magnolia</groupId>
        <artifactId>magnolia-module-standard-templating-kit</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.magnolia</groupId>
        <artifactId>magnolia-module-legacy-admininterface</artifactId>
        <version>5.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.magnolia.ui</groupId>
        <artifactId>magnolia-ui-admincentral</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.magnolia.activation</groupId>
        <artifactId>magnolia-module-activation</artifactId>
        <version>5.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.magnolia</groupId>
        <artifactId>magnolia-templating</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.4</version>
    </dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>info.magnolia.cache</groupId>
  <artifactId>magnolia-module-cache</artifactId>
  <version>5.0.3</version>
</dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>info.magnolia</groupId>
      <artifactId>magnolia-jaas</artifactId>
<!--       <version>4.3.1</version> -->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.magnolia.ui</groupId>
        <artifactId>magnolia-ui-framework</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.magnolia.ui</groupId>
        <artifactId>magnolia-ui-contentapp</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.magnolia</groupId>
        <artifactId>magnolia-module-scheduler</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>info.magnolia.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>magnolia-security-app</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.4</version>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>info.magnolia</groupId>
  <artifactId>magnolia-module-fckeditor</artifactId>
  <version>4.5</version>
</dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>info.magnolia</groupId>
      <artifactId>magnolia-module-mail</artifactId>
      <version>5.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.magnolia</groupId>
        <artifactId>magnolia-module-categorization</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.jackrabbit</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackrabbit-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>net.sourceforge.openutils</groupId>
      <artifactId>openutils-log4j</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.magnolia</groupId>
        <artifactId>magnolia-demo-project</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.magnolia</groupId>
        <artifactId>magnolia-module-dms</artifactId>
        <version>1.6</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <!-- these are the resources copied by the remote-resources-plugin -->
        <directory>${basedir}/target/maven-shared-archive-resources</directory>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>**/*</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <filesets>
            <fileset>
              <directory>src/main/webapp/cache</directory>
            </fileset>
            <fileset>
              <directory>src/main/webapp/logs</directory>
            </fileset>
            <fileset>
              <directory>src/main/webapp/repositories</directory>
            </fileset>
<!--             <fileset> -->
<!--               <directory>src/main/webapp/templates</directory> -->
<!--             </fileset> -->
            <fileset>
              <directory>src/main/webapp/tmp</directory>
            </fileset>
          </filesets>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <webResources>
            <resource>
              <!-- these are the resources copied by the remote-resources-plugin -->
              <directory>${basedir}/target/maven-shared-archive-resources</directory>
            </resource>
          </webResources>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <scanIntervalSeconds>5</scanIntervalSeconds>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>net.sf.alchim</groupId>
        <artifactId>winstone-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>embed</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>package</phase>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>magnolia.nexus.public</id>
            <url>http://nexus.magnolia-cms.com/content/groups/public</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>vaadin-addons</id>
            <url>http://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>magnolia</id>
            <url>http://repo.magnolia-cms.com/m2</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
</project>
```

Now when I start magnolia-empty-project, I come to the magnolia installation page. When I click on "Start installation", it comes the following message:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BTW if anyone runs into this issue, to get rid of it, go to `WEB-INF/config/default/magnolia.properties` and add something like:

```
magnolia.author.key.location=${magnolia.home}/WEB-INF/config/default/magnolia-activation-keypair.properties
```

Pls note that while this is fine for development, you should keep all the files, incl. the keys *outside* of the (exploded) war file for production use.

Also related (but off topic for the discussion) - you should not need to have DMS in your pom file. Magnolia 5 doesn't need DMS. It was replaced by DAM. Pom file above looks like generated by some old version of the archetype or copied from old project.

HTH,
Jan

Comment: Yes I got it from old Tutorial: http://dev.magnolia-cms.com/~gjoseph/dont-build-magnolia-build-your-projects and that was my mistake

Answer (score 1):

Max,

I think the problem here is that you are mixing up two different versions of Magnolia. You say you checked out the empty webapp tagged 4.3.1 and then made a lot of changes to it. Have you tried checking out a v5 webapp from the [Git repository](http://git.magnolia-cms.com/gitweb/) that replaces the SVN one?

Alternatively, you may find it easier to use the [Maven archetypes](http://dev.magnolia-cms.com/~gjoseph/dont-build-magnolia-build-your-projects).

Answer (score 0):

here is the easiest way to get magnolia5 running with an empty-project:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aU7q3daQ8S0#t=133