# Magnolia Activation Module (version 5.2.3) Ensures that the key property 'magnolia.author.key.location' is present in the Magnolia properties file

Tags: java, magnolia

I have an issue on Magnolia Authoring.

I updated a template module jar, having some changes on FTL files only.

After restarting the Magnolia service, Magnolia notified me to install the Magnolia Activation Module:

```
Magnolia Activation Module (version 5.2.3)
install for module Activation version 5.2.3
```

The message told me to check the magnolia properties file looking for the magnolia.author.key.location, but the configuration looks right as described in this question

[Magnolia Activation Module (version 5.1.0) Ensures that the key property 'magnolia.author.key.location' is present in the Magnolia properties file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23753621/magnolia-activation-module-version-5-1-0-ensures-that-the-key-property-magnol)

Answer (score 0):

Try just to copy the activation key `config:/server/activation@publicKey` from author to public instance. Alternatively you can first generate new one (in the Tools > Activation Tools app).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, but the problem is that Magnolia author does not start, so, I cannot access to the control panel.

Comment: Can you provide excerpt from the log file? If author instance doesn't start there must be more to it then just the above message.

Answer (score 0):

Ok,
we found a workaround.

I don't really know why the problem happened, but we solved altering the "Magnolia Activation Module " jar content, removing the bootstrap xml files in the mgnl-bootstrap folder.

This tells to magnolia to skip the bootstrap, installing the already existing module. After this, We replaced the jar with the original one, than restarted it again.

This works good and the magnolia authoring has been started again.

Thanks to the Magnolia Forum for the support, Davide.